# Running A Function On Items In Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have a table that contains an object. I'd like to go through and call a member function on each one that will change some values on each of the objects. The problem is that my current method doesn't change the objects, but instead seems to create new ones and doesn't save the changes in the table.

My code looks something like

```
declare
  type row_type is table of my_table%rowtype;
  my_rows row_type;
begin
  select * bulk collect into my_rows from my_table;
  for i in my_table.first .. my_table.last loop
    my_table(i).stored_class.add_func(1);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```

With some schema that looks like.

```
create table my_table
(
    stored_class my_class
);

create type my_class as object
(
    my_num number,
    member procedure add_func(in_number number)
);

create type my_class body is
    member procedure add_func(in_number number) is
    begin
        my_num := my_num + in_number;
    end
end;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have to issue proper sql commands when you want to write back the object onto the database. Plsql is still something different from sql. Obecj attributes are simply variables in ram when you use them in plsql, they  are not database fields.

Comment: use cursor (containing an id or rowid), fetch into variable, manipulate object, update row using rowid and manipulated object.